# IE not supporting HTML5 background audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-player, background-music

I added a html5 audio tag to play background music in my website www.missduniya.com it works in all major browser but it does not work with IE.

Here is my code

```
<audio controls="CONTROLS" autoplay="autoplay" style="display:none;">
<source src="destination.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="destination.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Please help me by providing solution :)
Thanks

Comment: Please specify which version of IE.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you aren't using IE9.

HTML5 isn't fully supported by Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8

look at the following tables:
http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/

mainly this:

**Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8**
[image]

Comment: Reason #7124 no one should use IE.